# How to perform a caret change in a VisualStudio.Extensibility Extension project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

In a VisualStudio.Extensibility Extension project (VS2022), I can modify the currently edited Document from a Command by running

```
public override async Task ExecuteCommandAsync(IClientContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{        
    using var textView = await context.GetActiveTextViewAsync(cancellationToken);
    await Extensibility.Editor().EditAsync(batch =>
    {
        var doc = textView.Document.AsEditable(batch);
        ...
    }
}
```

But I din't find any way to change the caret location, the ITextViewSnapshot.Selection object is read-only.

However according to the documentation it's supposed to be possible:

```
For the initial release of the new Visual Studio extensibility model, only the following capabilities are supported   
...  
* Performing text edits and selection/caret changes.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visualstudio.extensibility/editor/editor?view=vs-2022

My question is how to move the caret?

### Edit

The code below adds a new caret at the specified location, however I can't find a way to remove the initial one; it seems SetSelections is actually adding selections

```
return Extensibility.Editor().EditAsync(batch =>
    {
        var snapshot = args.AfterTextView;

        var document = snapshot.Document.AsEditable(batch);
        int offset = snapshot.Selection.InsertionPosition.Offset;
        document.Insert(offset, "-");

        var position = new TextPosition(snapshot.Document, offset);
        var selections = new List<Selection>
        {
            new (position, position, position)
        };
        var textView = snapshot.AsEditable(batch);
        textView.SetSelections(selections);
    },
cancellationToken);
```